# renewal date less than to-day's date in pandas

Tags: pandas, date

I have below Dataframe in pandas, **condition is 15 days**, if Renewal date is equal 15 days is should say "Y", if Renewal date has already passed to-day date it should "Y", else it should as "N"

```
Dataframe                       

Renew Date  Premises                    
27-Dec-19   A                   
9-Dec-19    B                   
28-Dec-19   C                   


Output                      

To-day   Premises    Renew Date  Days   Y / N   Remarks 
12-Dec-19   A        27-Dec-19     15    "Y"    15 days to renewal  
12-Dec-19   B         9-Dec-19     -3    "Y"    -3 days to renewal  
12-Dec-19   C        28-Dec-19     16    "N"    16 days to renewal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df['Renew Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Renew Date"]) #change to datetime if string
df['Today'] = pd.Timestamp('now').normalize()
df['Days'] = (df['Renew Date'] - df['Today']).dt.days
df['Y / N'] = np.where(df['Days']>15, 'N', 'Y')
df['Remarks'] = [f'{i} days to renew' for i in df['Days']]
df
```

Output:

```
  Renew Date Premises      Today  Days Y / N           Remarks
0 2019-12-27        A 2019-12-12    15     Y  15 days to renew
1 2019-12-09        B 2019-12-12    -3     Y  -3 days to renew
2 2019-12-28        C 2019-12-12    16     N  16 days to renew
```